# Em R, corrigir erros de digitação seguido de um tratamento de uma base de dados

Tags: r

Este problema é bastante complexo e precisa de dois estágios. O primeiro estágio consiste em corrigir erros de digitação de uma base de dados(talvez uma solução probabilística). O segundo estágio consiste em arrumar esta base de dados depois desta correção. Este segundo estágio requer uma sequência de aplicações do pacote dplyr(ou outro pacote adequado e elegante)

Vamos ao primeiro estágio. Eu tenho uma base de dados de uma empresa. A base de dados disponibilizada não revela completamente a identidade do trabalhador. Vou exemplificar a base para depois explicar as variáveis.

```
data <- read.table(text="
              cpf;nome;m1;m2;m3;m4;m5;m6;m7;m8;m9;m10;m11;m12;salario
              100001;Maria dos Santos Magalhães;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;1234
              100001;Maria Santos Magalhães;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;1;1;1;1034
              100002;Lucas Barbosa;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;4234 
              100002;Danilo Carvalho;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;7234
              100003;Paulo Silva de Fonseca;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;1254
              100003;Paulo Silva da Fonseca;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;2234
              100003;Wagner Silva Junior;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;4234
              100003;Paulo Silva Fonseca;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1232
              100004;Ricardo Colho;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;1;1;1;0;5234
              100004;Ricardo Coelho;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;1;1234", h=T, sep=";")
```

Explicando as variáveis. Primeiro, não temos o cpf completo, só temos os 6 números do meio. A variável "nome" dispensa explicações. As variáveis do tipo m1,m2,m3, etc são os meses. Estas variáveis são binárias e 1 representa que o trabalhador trabalhou no mês em questão e 0 que não trabalhou. A variável "salario" é o valor que o trabalhador ganhou nos messes trabalhados. Os dados aqui apresentados são fictícios.

Primeira coisa a ser observada olhando cada grupo de cpfs é que existe erros de digitação. Por exemplo, o grupo cujo número do meio de cpf é 100001, temos com grande chance de que  Maria dos Santos Magalhães e Maria Santos Magalhães sejam a mesma pessoa. Uma outra evidência é que se fosse duas pessoas diferentes, provavelmente teriam meses de trabalho em comum, como é o caso do cpf 100002, onde Lucas Barbosa e Danilo Carvalho são pessoas diferentes. Os outros casos seguem a mesma explicação.

Preciso de algum algoritmo que me indique, por exemplo, que Maria dos Santos Magalhães e Maria Santos Magalhães são, como probabilidade alta, a mesma pessoa. Assim como Lucas Barbosa e Danilo Carvalho são praticamente pessoas diferentes.

Uma tentativa usando adist:

```
teste<- data[data$cpf == 100003 , ]
(ch1<- teste$nome) 
[1] Paulo Silva de Fonseca Paulo Silva da Fonseca Wagner Silva Junior   
[4] Paulo Silva Fonseca   
10 Levels: Danilo Carvalho Lucas Barbosa ... Wagner Silva Junior

(d1 <- ch1 %>% adist())
         [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]        0    1   14    3
[2,]        1    0   14    3
[3,]       14   14    0   11
[4,]        3    3   11    0
```

Vou excluir os que tem distância zero e menor que 5 como padrão. Mas antes vou dar nome às linhas e colunas.

```
(d1<- as.data.frame(d1)) 
names(d1)<- ch1
row.names(d1)<- ch1
thresh=5
(teste<- which(d1 != 0 & d1 < thresh, arr.ind=TRUE) )
                        row col
 Paulo Silva da Fonseca   2   1
 Paulo Silva Fonseca      4   1
 Paulo Silva de Fonseca   1   2
 Paulo Silva Fonseca      4   2
 Paulo Silva de Fonseca   1   4
 Paulo Silva da Fonseca   2   4
```

Reparem que neste caso particular, Wagner Silva Junior não tem nenhuma ligação com os outros. A partir de agora, começa o segundo estágio: Com esta matriz de distâncias, eu gostaria de fazer uma série de manipulações de maneira a arrumar os nomes, os meses trabalhados e o salário. Em resumo, gostaria de algo como isto:

```
      cpf                       nome m1 m2 m3 m4 m5 m6 m7 m8 m9 m10 m11 m12 salario

2  100001     Maria Santos Magalhães  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1   1   1    2268
3  100002              Lucas Barbosa  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1   1   1    4234
4  100002            Danilo Carvalho  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1   1   0    7234
5  100003     Paulo Silva de Fonseca  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1   1   1    4720
7  100003        Wagner Silva Junior  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0    4234
9  100004              Ricardo Colho  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1   1   1    6468
```

Acredito que uma série de funções usando o dplyr possa resolver este segundo estágio

Comment: conseguiu resolver?

Comment: @FlavioBarros , Não

Comment: @orrillo ainda interessa a solução? pois tenho algo em mente, e posso desenvolver a resposta!

Comment: Pode postar. Sempre é bom a contribuição

Answer (score 4):

**Introdução**

Eu tive um problema similar a esse em 2017, e eu resolvi a partir da lógica Fuzzy, com base nesse [link](https://andrewwhitby.com/2016/02/24/fuzzy-matching-multiword-strings-sentences-in-r/) de 2016.

No link, o autor explica que ele pega cada setença (que nesse caso é um nome completo), separa por palavra e usa a [distância de Levenshtein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) para calcular quanto uma palavra está distante da outra, e por fim, pondera pelo tamanho das palavras (resumidamente é isso).

No final, o código resulta em um score fuzzy da correspondência das palavras (quanto maior melhor, e +Inf implica numa correspondência exata).

**Corrigir erros de digitação**

Carregam-se as funções:

```
############################################################################ ###
### FUZZY MATCHING FUNCTIONS                                                  ####
############################################################################ ###
fuzzy_prep_words <- function(words) {
  # Prepares a list of words for fuzzy matching. All the other fuzzy matching
  # functions will run word through this. Given a list of sentences, returns
  # a list of words.

  words <- unlist(strsplit(tolower(gsub("[[:punct:]]", " ", words)), "\\W+"))
  return(words)
}

fuzzy_gen_word_freq <- function(l, fun = identity) {
  # Returns a word frequency vector based on vector of sentences l and with
  # frequencies post-processed by fun (e.g. log)

  fun(sort(table(fuzzy_prep_words(unlist(strsplit(l, ' ')))), decreasing=T))+1
}

fuzzy_title_match <- function(a, b, wf) {
  # Fuzzy matches a performance title based on a custom algorithm tuned for
  # this purpose. Words are frequency-weighted (like tf-idf).
  # 
  # Args:
  #   a, b: the two titles to match
  #   wf: a vector of word frequencies as generated by fuzzy_gen_word_freq
  #
  # Returns:
  #   A fuzzy match score, higher is better, +Inf for exact match

  if (a == b) # Shortcut to make faster
    return (Inf)
  a.words <- fuzzy_prep_words(a)
  b.words <- fuzzy_prep_words(b)
  a.freqs <- sapply(a.words, function(x) { ifelse(is.na(wf[x]), 1, wf[x]) })
  b.freqs <- sapply(b.words, function(x) { ifelse(is.na(wf[x]), 1, wf[x]) })

  d <- adist(a.words, b.words)
  a.matches <- 1-apply(d, 1, function(x) { min(x, 2) })/2
  b.matches <- 1-apply(d, 2, function(x) { min(x, 2) })/2

  matchsum <- min(sum(a.matches * 1/a.freqs), sum(b.matches * 1/b.freqs))
  unmatchsum <- sum(floor(1-a.matches) * 1/a.freqs) + sum(floor(1-b.matches) * 1/b.freqs)
  return(matchsum / unmatchsum)
}
```

Nomes que você quer calcular o escore *fuzzy* (nesse caso, é o mesmo nome):

```
A <- as.character(data$nome)
B <- as.character(data$nome)
```

Aplique nas funções:

```
wf <- fuzzy_gen_word_freq(c(A, B))
vectorised_match <- function (L1,L2) { mapply(function(a,b) { fuzzy_title_match(a, b, wf) }, L1, L2) } 
scores <- outer(A, B, vectorised_match)
rownames(scores) <- A
colnames(scores) <- B
```

Retorna uma matriz com o score fuzzy da distância entre cada um dos nomes:

```
> scores
                           Maria dos Santos Magalhães Maria Santos Magalhães Lucas Barbosa Danilo Carvalho Paulo Silva de Fonseca Paulo Silva da Fonseca Wagner Silva Junior
Maria dos Santos Magalhães                        Inf                    1.8             0               0             0.00000000             0.00000000          0.00000000
Maria Santos Magalhães                            1.8                    Inf             0               0             0.00000000             0.00000000          0.00000000
Lucas Barbosa                                     0.0                    0.0           Inf               0             0.00000000             0.00000000          0.00000000
Danilo Carvalho                                   0.0                    0.0             0             Inf             0.00000000             0.00000000          0.00000000
Paulo Silva de Fonseca                            0.0                    0.0             0               0                    Inf                    Inf          0.08641975
Paulo Silva da Fonseca                            0.0                    0.0             0               0                    Inf                    Inf          0.08641975
Wagner Silva Junior                               0.0                    0.0             0               0             0.08641975             0.08641975                 Inf
Paulo Silva Fonseca                               0.0                    0.0             0               0             1.19047619             1.19047619          0.11666667
Ricardo Colho                                     0.0                    0.0             0               0             0.00000000             0.00000000          0.00000000
Ricardo Coelho                                    0.0                    0.0             0               0             0.00000000             0.00000000          0.00000000
                           Paulo Silva Fonseca Ricardo Colho Ricardo Coelho
Maria dos Santos Magalhães           0.0000000             0              0
Maria Santos Magalhães               0.0000000             0              0
Lucas Barbosa                        0.0000000             0              0
Danilo Carvalho                      0.0000000             0              0
Paulo Silva de Fonseca               1.1904762             0              0
Paulo Silva da Fonseca               1.1904762             0              0
Wagner Silva Junior                  0.1166667             0              0
Paulo Silva Fonseca                        Inf             0              0
Ricardo Colho                        0.0000000           Inf            Inf
Ricardo Coelho                       0.0000000           Inf            Inf
```

Em teoria, somente, isso deveria funcionar, mas não é o caso:

```
A <- as.data.frame(A)
names(A) <- c("nome")
A$Nome1 <- colnames(scores)[apply(scores,1,which.max)]
A
                         nome                      Nome1
1  Maria dos Santos Magalhães Maria dos Santos Magalhães
2      Maria Santos Magalhães     Maria Santos Magalhães
3               Lucas Barbosa              Lucas Barbosa
4             Danilo Carvalho            Danilo Carvalho
5      Paulo Silva de Fonseca     Paulo Silva de Fonseca
6      Paulo Silva da Fonseca     Paulo Silva de Fonseca
7         Wagner Silva Junior        Wagner Silva Junior
8         Paulo Silva Fonseca        Paulo Silva Fonseca
9               Ricardo Colho              Ricardo Colho
10             Ricardo Coelho              Ricardo Colho
```

Mas como pode ser visto, não funcionou para as "Marias" e o "Paulo", então, são necessários mais manipulações nessa matriz de distâncias (a lógica Fuzzy já parou aqui, daqui para frente, é uma forma que eu pensei em solucionar).

Basicamente pego o escore e coloco na tabela dos nomes, faço uma tabela a partir da Pontuação, filtro aqueles com valores maiores que 1, e atribuo os nomes (a partir da tabela de nomes) às pontuações:

```
scores[is.infinite(scores)] <- NA # Faço isso, pois a correspondência exata de nomes já foi atribuída
A$Pontuacao <- as.numeric(apply(scores,1,max, na.rm = T))
tab <- table(A$Pontuacao)
# O ponto de corte a ser definido foi "1", mas isso pode ser melhor estudado a partir de uma amostra maior
aux <- tab[tab>1]
aux <- aux[names(aux)!="0"]
aux <- as.data.frame(aux)
aux <- aux[, -2, drop = F]
names(aux) <- "Pontuacao"
aux <- merge(aux, A[, c(2,3)], all.x = T)
```

Aqui, a partir da tabela de nomes original, eu faço um merge com a tabela que criei, e reatribuo os nomes a partir do ifelse:

```
aux <- aux[!duplicated(aux$Pontuacao), ]
aux$Pontuacao <- as.character(aux$Pontuacao)
A$Pontuacao <- as.character(A$Pontuacao)
names(aux)[2] <- "NomeNovo"
A <- merge(A, aux, all.x = T)
A$NomeNovo <- ifelse(is.na(A$NomeNovo), as.character(A$Nome1), as.character(A$NomeNovo))

           Pontuacao                       nome                      Nome1                   NomeNovo
1                  0              Ricardo Colho              Ricardo Colho              Ricardo Colho
2                  0             Ricardo Coelho              Ricardo Colho              Ricardo Colho
3                  0              Lucas Barbosa              Lucas Barbosa              Lucas Barbosa
4                  0            Danilo Carvalho            Danilo Carvalho            Danilo Carvalho
5  0.116666666666667        Wagner Silva Junior        Wagner Silva Junior        Wagner Silva Junior
6   1.19047619047619        Paulo Silva Fonseca        Paulo Silva Fonseca     Paulo Silva de Fonseca
7   1.19047619047619     Paulo Silva de Fonseca     Paulo Silva de Fonseca     Paulo Silva de Fonseca
8   1.19047619047619     Paulo Silva da Fonseca     Paulo Silva de Fonseca     Paulo Silva de Fonseca
9                1.8 Maria dos Santos Magalhães Maria dos Santos Magalhães Maria dos Santos Magalhães
10               1.8     Maria Santos Magalhães     Maria Santos Magalhães Maria dos Santos Magalhães
```

**Tratamento de uma base de dados**

Agora é fácil! Basta fazer o merge dos dados originais, com a tabela dos nomes arrumados, e somar as colunas agrupando pelo nome e CPF:

```
data2 <- merge(data, A[, c("nome", "NomeNovo")])
# Somo os salários e os meses pelo CPF e Nome
data2 <- aggregate(. ~ NomeNovo + cpf, data2[, -c(1)], sum)

# Aqui, é possível fazer um teste se algum nome foi agrupado de forma indevida
data2 <- data2[rowSums(data2[, -c(1:2, ncol(data2))])<=12, ]
# Como Não foi, eu paro por aqui, mas outras melhorias poderiam ser feitas
data2
                    NomeNovo    cpf m1 m2 m3 m4 m5 m6 m7 m8 m9 m10 m11 m12 salario
1 Maria dos Santos Magalhães 100001  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1   1   1    2268
2            Danilo Carvalho 100002  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1   1   0    7234
3              Lucas Barbosa 100002  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1   1   1    4234
4     Paulo Silva de Fonseca 100003  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1   1   1    4720
5        Wagner Silva Junior 100003  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0    4234
6              Ricardo Colho 100004  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1   1   1    6468
```